# Apple Thunderbolt Display Magsafe 1 to USB-C charge Macbook Air M1

Tags: thunderbolt, charging, power, magsafe

I have an MacBook Air M1 and Apple Thunderbolt Display:

- DisplayPort connected to Apple Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207266): Currently connected to MBA
- Magsafe 1 with Magsafe 2 adapter: Not in use

I am currently using original MBA Power Adapter to charge my laptop. I would like to use Magsafe to charge instead, which means I need a Magsafe 1/2 to USB-C adapter. One of the options is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08SBX99N1) but I am unwilling to spend so much for an adapter.

What are my other options? Thanks.

Comment: All adapters of that kind will be in a similar price range. What other solution are you seeking? IMO opinion this is the best solution. Why don't you use the original power cable in the first place?

Comment: Have you seen this one: https://www.conmdex.com/products/usb-c-to-magnetic-2-adapter
Not sure what the price was on your original adapter you posted, but this one is 20$